# Is the authorized_keys options field broken on MacOS Mojave?

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

My `authorized_keys` file looks like this:

```
from='127.0.0.1' ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCeAVHd//GTcItdubkzN+FzQYDlEIa9YxKK7jyg/uufjP/aKEMpa6ZVtZQPpzihmGV7uOrSEjC3QMyKz7eFhkej3eb8Igki9HrTwTQphH7RsBYnXBe9OXpDj21P4T0uUY5zHYzzH4Beb31nZxU++MEITfDbl49Ot6JFXS+NmS7O6yWePbOT4EtdriY+kxexkQT3YO/0wxZv1xbNVpguC100VoyzEEKAiCXT5kRDYNkpiHrPircI7D1QRG+9yNbCJYvrq39usB4hHOu5O5TnW1gYeE8gmQBGeKqHb+3fTzLpHGzi1qgOWyTlJX7rfFiu9ZMgcU+B9BPAbpsUZ4Gkx8AH
```

When I try to login with `ssh -4 localhost` I get `Permission denied (publickey).` but if I remove the options field I can login successfully. As far as I can tell from sshd(8) I'm using the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the format is wrong. You have to use double quotes.

```
from="127.0.0.1" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCeAVHd//GTcItdubkzN+FzQYDlEIa9YxKK7jyg/uufjP/aKEMpa6ZVtZQPpzihmGV7uOrSEjC3QMyKz7eFhkej3eb8Igki9HrTwTQphH7RsBYnXBe9OXpDj21P4T0uUY5zHYzzH4Beb31nZxU++MEITfDbl49Ot6JFXS+NmS7O6yWePbOT4EtdriY+kxexkQT3YO/0wxZv1xbNVpguC100VoyzEEKAiCXT5kRDYNkpiHrPircI7D1QRG+9yNbCJYvrq39usB4hHOu5O5TnW1gYeE8gmQBGeKqHb+3fTzLpHGzi1qgOWyTlJX7rfFiu9ZMgcU+B9BPAbpsUZ4Gkx8AH
```